# How do I specify eslint rule schema with array of objects

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-rule-schema

Trying to set a schema for my eslint rule.
The intended configuration is as follows:

```
'my-rule': ['error', [
  {'any-key': ['array', 'of', 'strings']},
  {'some-other-key': ['array', 'of', 'strings']},
  ...etc
]]
```

I found out that it is possible to allow any non-enum property names, but I'm not sure how to specify their value types:

```
    schema: [
        {
            type: 'array',
            items: {
                type: 'object',
                propertyNames: {
                    type: 'string',
                    // ??? - how do I specify array of strings here?
                },
            }
        }
    ],
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `propertyNames` to specify the value types.

Wouldn't [`patternProperties`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html?highlight=propertynames#property-names) work better for your purpose?

```
schema: [
    {
        type: 'array',
        items: {
            type: 'object',
            patternProperties: {
                ".": {
                    type: "array",
                    items: {type: "string"}
                }
            },
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works brilliant. I was so stuck on `propertyNames` that my eyes didn't notice `patternProperties`.